# Javascript - How to remove all active classes unless the element being clicked on already has a active class

Tags: javascript

```
    const offCanvasLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.off-canvas__link');

    [].forEach.call(offCanvasLinks, function(link) {
        link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            const typeVal = link.getAttribute('data-type') 

            if (typeVal === "star") {
                document.querySelector('[data-star-links]').classList.toggle('active');
            } else if (typeVal === "how-to") {
                document.querySelector('[data-how-to]').classList.toggle('active');
            } else {
                document.querySelector('[data-presenters]').classList.toggle('active');
            }
        })
    });
```

I have the above code that clicks on a navigation to toggle a class of active.

If I click on another element in the navigation I need to remove all active classes unless the clicked on element already has a active class.

In Jquery this is super easy with the ability to use .not(). Where you can just past through the event target to check and remove all other active classes.

So to make this more clear what I'm looking for is a way to remove all active classes unless the element being clicked has already got an active class.

Let me know your thoughts

*********** UPDATE ******************
Ok... 
Click on a link at the bottom it'll show a screen nicely if you then click on another link it will close the previous one then open the next one. HOWEVER if you click on the same link it does not close the menu.

how do I remove the class if it is already open?

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/2oqm0r2n/3/

Comment: The fiddle is not very useful as it shows nothing when being run.

Comment: Let me update Jsfiddle Trincot so you can see my problem, Keen to get this resolved

Comment: Hi Trincot, I've just updated my question. I hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: I don't understand. The following two phrases from your question seem to be asking two contradictory things: *"a way to remove all active classes unless the element being clicked has already got an active class. "*, versus: *"HOWEVER if you click on the same link it does not close the menu. how do I remove the class if it is already open?"*

Comment: Ok... I am struggling to put this into words. I guess what I'm trying to say is close the menu if it is clicked again or if you click on a different link from the bottom then to close the one open and open the newly clicked container.

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to *toggle* the *active* class of the element corresponding to the clicked item, and you want to *remove* the *active* class from all other elements.

This you can do as follows:

```
  if (typeVal === containerVal) {
    container.classList.toggle('active')
  } else {
    container.classList.remove('active')
  }
```

See your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2oqm0r2n/4/)

Or in one "line":

```
container.classList.toggle('active', typeVal === containerVal && 
                                     !container.classList.contains('active'));
```

...in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2oqm0r2n/5/)

Comment: You sir are a legend. Apologies for poor explanation.

Answer (score 2):

maybe something like this?

for example:

```
// unless the clicked on element has already an active class
if(!link.classList.contains('active')){
    // remove all active classes
    var actives = document.querySelectorAll('.active');
    [].forEach.call(actives, function(elem) {  
        elem.classList.remove("active");
    });
}
```

Comment: Nah this won't work because I need to toggle the class. So it'll remove all of them if it was active and then turn the clicked one into active again.

Comment: I updated the code with an if check, maybe I understood it wrong.

Comment: nah afraid that isn't what I'm looking for. I might be onto something thohg

Comment: I didn't understand what you exactly want.

Comment: You have written "remove all active classes unless the clicked on element has already an active class" three times, but the code I wrote is all that I've understood. Please clarify more.

Comment: Yeah basically I've got a different element im applying the active to than the clicked element. This js Fiddle should help:https://jsfiddle.net/2oqm0r2n/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139655/discussion-between-maxwelllynn-and-taha-paksu).

Comment: This answer corresponds to what one can understand from the question (+1).

Comment: I've just updated my question. I hope this makes more sense now.